# How to lay out a perspective to make the left region with two parts: top and bottom?

Tags: eclipse, layout, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-plugin

Tried both [Programmatic and Declarative way](http://www.modumind.com/2008/12/11/perspective-layouts-programmatic-vs-declarative/) but failed, and I just wanna make the left region lay out like below. Any hints?

[image: perspective]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've found a declarative way to handle this 
(which is inspired by the layout of Eclipse internal `CVS Repositories Exploring perspective` and decompiled its source code)

`plugin.xml`

`<!-- ************** Perspective Extensions START **************** -->
       <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions">
          <perspectiveExtension targetID="$YOUR_PERSPECTIVE_ID$">
            <view
                closeable="false"
                id="$BOTTOM_VIEW_ID$"
                moveable="false"
                ratio="0.6"
                relationship="bottom"
                relative="$TOP_VIEW_ID$"
                showTitle="true"
                standalone="true">
            </view>
          </perspectiveExtension>
       </extension>`

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder for the left column and then put two more folders in the column:

```java
IFolderLayout leftOuter = layout.createFolder("left.outer", IPageLayout.LEFT, 0.23f, IPageLayout.ID_EDITOR_AREA);

IFolderLayout leftTop = layout.createFolder("left.top", IPageLayout.TOP, 0.5f, "left.outer");

// TODO add views and placeholders to leftTop

IFolderLayout leftBottom = layout.createFolder("left.bottom", IPageLayout.BOTTOM, 0.5f, "left.outer");

// TODO add views and placeholders to leftBotton
```

Comment: I've tried your code which would create 3 folders and the leftOuter is never used and two tab folders are empty. I've found a declarative way by defination in `plugin.xml`, still lots of thanks.